# Reload table cache in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, arcgis-pro, features, cache

In ArcMap, it is very easy to reload table cache where it will call the CSV that was previously used to create the feature class to update the feature with any new data from the same CSV.

In ArcGIS Pro, it seems to me that once we create a feature layer from a CSV file, the attribute table of the feature layer is independent to the CSV file used. There doesn’t seem to be a way to reload table cache in ArcGIS Pro.

I’d like to be able to have the feature class updated using the same CSV (with new data added) instead of me recreating the feature every time we collect new data. This is so that I can preserve the symbology as well.

I’ve considered appending, but as some entries from previous import can change, I prefer to overwrite the attribute table in the feature class instead.

If this is possible using ArcGIS Pro or ArcPy, then how?

Edit: I tested with ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro, once the feature class is created, the attribute table is independent of the csv and reload table cache in ArcMap/ refresh in ArcGIS Pro will not update with the latest csv. So I guess there is not really away where I can update the attribute tables of a feature class without recreating the features using a new version of the csv?

Comment: What tool are you using to visualise your CSV file? Is it the make xy event layer tool?

Comment: @Hornbydd that is correct. it is the display XY data tool. But in ArcGIS Pro, it'd create a feature layer for you instead of an event layer in ArcMap.

Comment: Look at the note on this [page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/add-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm).

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd! What I was hoping to do is have those tables updated with the latest data in a feature class so that other users have access to it as well. Creating the event layer on the fly works but is only restricted to a project. Seems like a limitation of ArcGIS Pro.. But this option can definitely be a workaround for sure. Thanks again!